# Importing function from a py file while using the Python shell

Tags: python

[image]

I'm using the **Python shell** since i'm **learning** this programming language.

I've found a simple **script** on Github and i would like to save it as a python file and then import it while I'm using the Python shell, in order to use a function declared in this script.

In order to be **imported** from the Python shell, in which **path** do i need to save this script ? (I'm on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

There're several points to consider:

**1) Is downloading the script from Github is the only option?**
Many python libraries would be possible to install using `pip`, which will make it possible just to import library:

```sh
pip install mylibrary
```

**2) If it is not possible**, please refer to python import system explained here https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> 1) The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
>   2) PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
>   3) The installation-dependent default.

It seems that in your case it should be enough to start python shell from the same folder where the downloaded script is.

Note: it is not always legally possible to just download the script from github and use it, make sure to check the license.